# Vertex AI batch prediction results in ('ValueError', 1)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have a predictor that works successfully when run on a local container, but when that container is pushed to the Artifact Registry, and imported to a Vertex AI model, and run in Batch Prediction mode, it returns an empty prediction file and an error file that simply says `('ValueError', 1)`

The request is made using Flask.
code (main.py) is

```
if 'AIP_HEALTH_ROUTE' in os.environ:
    AIP_HEALTH_ROUTE = os.environ['AIP_HEALTH_ROUTE']
else:
    AIP_HEALTH_ROUTE = '/health'
    
if 'AIP_PREDICT_ROUTE' in os.environ:
    AIP_PREDICT_ROUTE = os.environ['AIP_PREDICT_ROUTE']
else:
    AIP_PREDICT_ROUTE = '/predict'
    
@app.route(AIP_HEALTH_ROUTE, methods=['GET'])
def health():
    response = {"message": "OK", "code": "SUCCESS"}
    return make_response(jsonify(response), 200)

@app.route(AIP_PREDICT_ROUTE, methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    try:
        instances = pd.DataFrame(request.json.get("instances"))
        # creates a model using model and encoders stored at given GCS location
        model = model_active.CustomPredictor('datascience-modelartifacts/my-model/actives')

        processed_data = model.process_score_data(instances)
        predictions = model.predict(processed_data)
        
        response = {"predictions": predictions}
        status = 200

    except Exception as e:
        response = {"error": str(e)}
        status = 500

    return make_response(jsonify(response), status)
```

For local testing, the data looks like:

```
dat = {"instances": [
    {"F1": 1000854828492, "F2": 3000076437878, "F3": 19.99, ...},
    {"F1": 1000222326963, "F2": 3000127917915, "F3": 19.99, ...},
    ... ]}
```

I call this with

```
import requests
url = 'http://localhost:5000/predict'
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept-Charset': 'UTF-8'}
r = requests.post(url, json=dat, headers=headers)
```

and in this case everything works as expected (I get a list of predicted classes returned).

I can successfully deploy this model as an endpoint and provide this data as test and get predictions returned.

However, for Vertex batch prediction (which is what I ultimately want to enable since we only need this model once a month), I have tried providing this data as both JSONL and CSV and I keep receiving output with no successful predictions and an error file that simply says `('ValueError', 1)`

Does anyone have any suggestions what this error means and what is causing it?

Comment: Did you check if you have to encode the JSON data to submit to Vertex AI endpoint ?

Comment: To submit to endpoint test you simply paste JSON data into a web form and submit.  This is what works successfully.

Comment: I haven't actually sent an endpoint request via code - I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

For me this was caused by not wrapping strings in my CSV in quotes, as referenced [here](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/tabular-data/classification-regression/get-batch-predictions#csv-file:%7E:text=You%20must%20enclose%20all%20strings%20in%20double%20quotation%20marks%20%28%22%29). This fixed it:

```
import csv

df.to_csv("outfile.csv", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
```